# passing literal string as const char * parameter causes code analyzer error

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, code-analysis, invalid-argument

I have overloaded function

```
int put_message(int level, int sys_log_level, const char * inp_message);
int put_message(int level, int sys_log_level, const std::string &inp_message);
```

and call this function

```
put_message(0, LOG_ERR, "clock_gettime error");
```

Code is compiled and works
but Eclipse CDT Code analyzer says

> Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   int put_message(int, int, const char *)
>   int put_message(int, int, const ? &)
>   '

How can I fix this the error?

Update:
After modifying LOG_ERR to int(LOG_ERR) error disappears.
I have not add the  in the header.
Adding  solves the problem.

Comment: Your code is well-formed. This may be a bug in the code analyzer.

Comment: What Eclipse/CDT version?

Comment: [This bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470943) seems to be very related (altough related to rvalues rather to lvalue references).

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `#include <string>` or something related to string class

Answer (score -2):

You need to cast the string to the correct type, the compiler treats "some string" as char[] so you need to cast it to const char*

Try with

```
put_message(0, LOG_ERR, (const char*)"clock_gettime error");
```

Comment: Nope. `const char[]`s decay into `const char*`, whereas `std::string` requires a user-defined conversion.

Comment: It should do if you pass the variable that corresponds to a pointer to the first char in the array but I've seen cases like this where a cast was required for string literals. Whether thats a bug in the code analyser as you said, I don't know

Comment: @Henry, I have try this. No changes. But I try (type)(val) for other arguments and find out source of error.